# Using view model in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, model-binding

I am trying to implement view model to get the data from multiple table. However, I am getting the following error

**InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'RoleManagement.Models.RolePermissionsViewModel' requires a key to be defined.**

Below is my view model

```
 public class RolePermissionsViewModel
{

    public List<LMS_RolePermissions> RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public List<LMS_UserPermissions> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Where LMS_RolePermissions and LMS_UserPermissions are two different tables in the database. Basically I want to get the data from these two tables in view model. To get the data I have written below code

```
 RolePermissionsViewModel rolemodel = new RolePermissionsViewModel
 {
    RolePermissions = dbContext.RolePermissions.ToList(),
    UserPermissions = dbContext.UserPermissions.ToList()
 };
```

and DBContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
    public DbSet<LMS_LocLanguage> LMS_LocLanguage { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LMS_Permissions> Permissions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<LMS_RolePermissions> RolePermissions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<LMS_UserPermissions> UserPermissions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<RolePermissionsViewModel> RoleUserPermission { get; set; }
}
```

I do not want to Key to be defined and table should NOT be created.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is advised to place seperately your domainmodels and viewmodels. all tables in the applicationcontext are created by  entity framework convention if if i use `DbSet<myclass>` or mention it in another class that used with `Dbset`. your answer should be [excluding types](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/included-types.html) with data annotations `NotMapped` and with fluent api `modelbuilder.ignore<RolePermissionsViewModel>();`. (of course,you will remove `DbSet` firstly. if i read and understand correctly, you say to your codes "please dont create this,i beg on you" after you command database to set.)